# How to add a route to a ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I've been creating a gem and I need to create a route that maps to a controller in the gem.

I have a file ( *config/routes.rb* ) which looks like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  match "rest/*path" => "bconnected/apis#rest"

end
```

My controller lives in *app/controllers/bconnected/apis_controller.rb*

My gemspecs file includes all of these files.

I run gem build, and gem install.

I include my gem in the rails Gemfile but when I try to hit that URL I get:

*No route matches [GET] "/rest/test"*'

Do I need to do anything special for Rails to read my routes.rb file from the gem?

Comment: I figured out that you need to make your Gem an "Engine". Follow this tutorial and it will work: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/06/23/a-guide-to-starting-your-own-rails-engine-gem/